# Getting this action is unauthorized in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting This action is unauthorized 403 when i enter url localhost/website/post/1/edit. i want to protect to edit post from unauthorized user .

in PostController

```
public function edit($id)
{
$post=Post::findOrFail($id);
$this->authorize('check_access',$post);
return 'You are authorized';
}
```

In AuthServiceProvider.php

```
protected $policies = [
Post::class => 'PostPolicy::class',
];
```

in PostPolicy.php

```
public function check_access($post)
{
return Auth::user()->id==$post->user_id;
}
```

In web.php
`Route::resource('post','PostController');`

Please Tell Where i am wrong . i am new in laravel and totally frustrated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be totally frustrated my friend. You should read the documentation for better understanding on the code you are trying to write. So just follow the example [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#writing-policies) and you should be all good to go. So instead of accessing the user from the `Auth` guard, you can pass it through to the method as first parameter.

```
public function check_access(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id == $post->user_id;
}
```